# ttk buttons in python dict reference to the same object, generation problem?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter, ttk

I'm really confused about the problem I'm facing. I've spent some time trying to aisle the problem as much as I can, and here it is:

Im working with tkinter and ttk, and I want to create a grid of buttons, just like in this code:(Taken from https://www.edureka.co/community/1539/tkinter-grid-overlapping-issue)
**TL;DR:** Just a working calendar that has a button per day in a grid

```
from calendar import *
import datetime
try:
    from tkinter import *   # Python 3.x
except:
    from Tkinter import *   # Python 2.x


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

        DateNow = datetime.datetime.now()
        month = int(DateNow.month)
        year = int(DateNow.year)
        self.createDaysOfWeekLabels()
        month_name = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        # Create frames and button controls for previous, current and next month.
        self.frameList = []    # List that contains the frame objects.
        self.buttonList = []   # List that contains the button objects.
        amonth = month - 1
        for i in range(3):
            if amonth < 0:
                amonth = 11
                year -= 1
            elif amonth == 12:
                amonth = 1
                year += 1

            mFrame = Frame(self)
            self.createMonth(mFrame, amonth, year)
            self.frameList.append(mFrame)
            mButton = Button(self, text=month_name[amonth-1])
            mButton['command'] = lambda f=mFrame, b=mButton: self.showMonth(f, b)
            mButton.grid(row=0, column=i)
            # Grid each frame
            mFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=7, sticky='news')
            if (i == 1):
                mButton['relief'] = 'flat'
            else:
                # Remove all but the ith frame. More efficient to remove than forget and configuration is remembered.
                mFrame.grid_remove()
            self.buttonList.append(mButton)
            amonth += 1

        # Create year widget at top left of top frame
        label = Label(self, text=year)#displaying year
        label.grid(row=0, column=6)


    def createDaysOfWeekLabels(self):
        days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
        for i in range(7):
            label = Label(self, text=days[i])
            label.grid(row = 1, column = i)

    def showMonth(self, mFrame, mButton):
        # Display all buttons normally
        for button in self.buttonList:
            button['relief'] = 'raised'

        # Set this month's button relief to flat
        mButton['relief'] = 'flat'

        # Hide all frames
        for frame in self.frameList:
            frame.grid_remove()

        mFrame.grid()

    def createMonth(self, mFrame, month, year):
        weekday, numDays = monthrange(year, month)
        week = 0
        for i in range(1, numDays + 1):
            button = Button(mFrame, text = str(i), width=3)
            button.grid(row = week, column = weekday)

            weekday += 1

            if weekday > 6:
                week += 1
                weekday = 0

mainWindow = Tk()
obj = Application(mainWindow)
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

then I tried to do something similar but using a dictionary whose key is a coordinate tuple and the value is the button(which has a frame as a parent), like this:

```
coords = {(0, 0):ttk.Button(self.frame_p1g), (0, 1): ttk.Button(self.frame_p1g)}
```

I just used this same dict for my grid, and this code down here, and it works perfectly:

```
x = 2
    for i in coords.values():
        i.grid(row=x, column=2)
        x += 1
```

[Image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll7U6.png)

But as soon as I use a simple function to generate a grid automatically, and then place it in the grid, it doesn't work:

```
def make(width, height, element):
grid = {}
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        print ("X: " + str(x))
        print ("Y: " + str(y))
        grid[x, y] = element
return grid
```

[Image with result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biwZL.png)

I tried to find the cause, but the only thing I could find was that the function seems to create exact same buttons, and somehow when I try to place them, every button gets the same row and column config:

[Dict print from working dict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNDf2.png)

[Dict print from bugged list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvURK.png)

And this is the code that places each button(just pretty similar to the other, just using the lengh of the dict to know where to place them)

```
    self.p1g = make(int(self.size[0]), int(self.size[1]), ttk.Button(self.frame_p1g))
    print(self.p1g)
    x = 2
    y = 2
    for butt in self.p1g.values():
        butt.grid(row=y, column=x)
        x += 1
        if x > (list(self.p1g.keys())[-1][0]):
            x = 2
            y += 1
```

**The question:** How can I make it work with a dict?(I really need those coordinates to reference the buttons)

Comment: I recommend by starting with a single function that creates the grid and does nothing else. You've posted too much extra code that isn't relevant to the question being asked, which makes it hard to read and understand. It's important to narrow the code down to the smallest [mcve] possible.

Comment: It references to the same object because `make` function operates on only one `element`, hence one element has one set of coordinates at a time. Is there a problem with creating buttons inside of the `make` instead of passing one? Looks like someone's inattention or I missed something.